# How can I select on doGet(e) function between HtmlService and ContentService from HTML form?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, callback

I'm trying to select a working mode on doGet(e) on my Google Script App when a function on the HTML form finish but I not sure how can I do it. The Google Script App is already embed with IFRAME on my webpage and from the webpage I make a callback to Google Script with a JSONP and works perfect but I need to make the call with a **setinterval** to get the response from the Google Script only when the HTML finish. It is the only way I think I can receive de response from Google Scrip. On Google.gs now works with a conditional to return between HtmlService or ContentService if I call it, but I want allow only the ContentService when the function showSuccess() run from the HTML. How can I do it? Thanks you.

**CallBack from my Webpage to change a h1 (like an example):**

```
var refreshCall = setInterval(test, 1000);

function test() {
$.getJSON('https://script.google.com/macros/s/SCRIPT_ID/exec?prefix=?', null, function (results) {
    $('h1').html(results);
                });
}
```

**Google.gs:**

```
function doGet(e) { //HOW SHOULD I CHANGE THIS TO RETURN ONLY ContentService WHEN THE FUNCTION " showSuccess()" ON "forms.html" ALLOW IT
  if (e.parameter.prefix){
    var result = 'Hello World';
    var content = e.parameters.prefix + '(' +JSON.stringify(result) + ')';
    
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(content)
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
  }
  else {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('forms');
    return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  }
}
```

**forms.html on Google Script App project**

```
<script>    
function showSuccess() {
    //HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO CALL doGet(e) TO ALLOW ONLY ContentService
          }
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1qtpm2so/)

I create a JSFIDDLE to explain better with an example but with a button instead of a interval.  If you click on the Run "showSuccess()" a DONE text appear to show the execution of the function on the HTML from GAS project. If you click on GET DATA button, the title TO CHANGE change to STACKOVERFLOW always. I need that 'GET DATA' button only works when the DONE appear.
This is the Script Project Example [PROJECT](https://script.google.com/d/1ex_m7blcdcGUBK4L5BJwVQxIldFQm55PshsNano-7xFfRTAGoXJkIFq2/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You could put another google.script.run in the setInterval function and receive the return with successHandler but you can’t use google.script.run.doGet(e) unless you create the event object. I’ve seen people try this and the doGet does run but without the event object there are no parameters.

Comment: I redact badly the question, now is edit correctly, sorry. Now the code have comments to be clear about what I'm trying to do. Calling google.script.run.doGet(e) was only an example, because I don´t know how to implement it. Thank you @Cooper

Comment: Where is your HTML file? For example, your HTML file is included in the Google Apps Script project? Or, it is put to the outside of Google?

Comment: `doGet()` can run only one time - and it has to be the first function when the page is loaded. If you want to call from client side an Apps Script funciton - this function needs to have a different name.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, the HTML is included in the Google Apps Script project.

Comment: @ziganotschka But then when I callback from my webpage with `exec?prefix=?` to get the "Hello World" from the Google Script, the doGet() don't run again to return the value?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Yes, the HTML is included in the Google Apps Script project.`, I would like to propose to use `google.script.run` for retrieving values from Google Apps Script side instead of `$.getJSON()`. How about this? But I'm not sure about your actual situation. So if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike any suggestion is great! But maybe I explain bad on my question. The HTML that is say it is on Google Script project is the last part of code named with `"forms.html on Google Script App"`, for sure is just a part of the code. The first part `"CallBack from my Webpage to change a h1 (like an example):"` is the HTML on the website, for that reason I don't know how to call from my website using `google.script.run`, if this even possible?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your situation, the HTML&Javascript of "CallBack" is put to the outside of GAS project. And, "forms.html" is included in the GAS project. I think that I could correctly understand about your situation.

Comment: In this case, I would like to propose to use `fetch` api of Javscript in `$.getJSON()`. By this, after `$.getJSON()` was run, `HtmlService` can be returned by `fetch`. Or, how about requesting to Web Apps using `fetch` instead of `$.getJSON()`? By this, `return ContentService...` is not required. The sample script for using `fetch` to `doGet` can be seen at https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#samplescriptvariouslanguages If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike My English is bad too. My problem is fetch data from the `doGet(e)` (in this case the ´'Hello World'` from `var result`) only when the function `showSuccess()` from the HTML of the GAS project was execute, and not always. I create a JSFIDDLE to explain better. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/1qtpm2so/) If you click on the `Run "showSuccess()"` a DONE text appear to show the execution of the function on the HTML from GAS project. If you click on `GET DATA` button, the title TO CHANGE change to STACKOVERFLOW always. I need that 'GET DATA' button only works when the DONE appear.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I cannot understand about `I need that 'GET DATA' button only works when the DONE appear.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike Of course. I mean that when I press the Button "GET DATA" to do the callback to receive the `var result = 'STACKOVERFLOW'` from the GAS ContentService, I want this only works if the function `showSuccess()` was execute, not always. If you check the JSFIDDLE (I also edit the post with the JSFIDDLE) you can see how when I press the GET DATA button, the script send the data to the JSFIDDLE, but I want to receive that data ONLY if the `showSuccess()` was execute, in the JSFIDDLE case is when you press the button Run "showSuccess()". Here is the script that run on the JSFIDDLE

Comment: @Tanaike [script example](https://script.google.com/d/1ex_m7blcdcGUBK4L5BJwVQxIldFQm55PshsNano-7xFfRTAGoXJkIFq2/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, you want to change HTML, which is put in outside of Google Apps Script project, outside of `iframe` by clicking a button in `iframe` which is put in Google Apps Script project. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes! Exactly!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could confirm that I could understand about your goal. In that case, I have no solution for achieving your goal. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike But can a function that is inside the Google Apps Script project (the HTML file in it)  allow or block a ContentService on the doGet(e) from the .gs file? I just need a way to do that, the rest I could do it by myself.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I cannot understand about `But can a function that is inside the Google Apps Script project (the HTML file in it) allow or block a ContentService on the doGet(e) from the .gs file?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike of course. Let me explain:
· The Google Apps Script project have two files; the `Google.gs` and the `forms.html`
· I have the doGet(e) function with the code you see on the Google.gs file at the top of this post. That function allow with an ìf` conditional to return a `ContentService.createTextOutput(content)` or `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('forms')`.
· In the HTML file (forms.html) I have a function named showSuccess(). This function works when I press a button
· I need this function allow the `ContentService` from the doGet(e) instead of the ìf` that I code on it

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I would like to confirm my understanding of your goal again. You want to change HTML, which is put in outside of Google Apps Script project, outside of iframe by clicking a button in iframe which is put in Google Apps Script project. About this, is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes and no. I just want to receive whatever data from the Google Apps Script when is call it from outside the iframe (with an interval or with a button) only when the Google Apps Script finish a function from inside the Google Apps Script project html file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: No problem @Tanaike . For sure my english don't help. Maybe other user can help. Thank you for your time.